# How to transfer selected value of first ListView to second ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-sdk-2.3

I have two `ListView`s in one activity. I want to transfer the value of the selected item from the first to the second `ListView` through a `Button`s `onClick()`. Please see my codes below.

**activity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.edkul.vimal.edkul.Library">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Library"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="25sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#88FF0000"
            android:padding="3dp">

        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/previousButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
package com.edkul.vimal.edkul;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Library extends Activity {

     String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};

     Button btn1,btn2;
     ArrayAdapter adapter1,adapter2;
     String[] data;
    ListView listView1,listView2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_library);

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item1);
        listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item3);

        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
                String selectedFromList = (String) (listView1.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
                Log.v("Print Here", selectedFromList.toString());
                data[0] = selectedFromList.toString();
                adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, data[0]);
            }
        });

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

[image: Please refer the image for more explanation.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try like this.**

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
              String clickedItem = mobileArray[postion];
              if(!arrayData.contains(clickedItem))
                 arrayData.add(clickedItem);
              String[] newitem = new String[arrayData.size()];
              arrayData.toArray(newitem);
              adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Library.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, newitem);
            }
        });
```

**Here arrayData is your list array define it Globally.**

```
List<String> arrayData = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Then on button click set your adapter.**

```
       btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            }
        });
```

**Hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Comment: what would the value of postion may be that is silly question but please help me out.And I am getting error in adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, newitem); cannnot resolve the constructor.

Comment: @vimalmishra Position is your myItemInt varialbe replace it with position their.

Comment: @vimalmishra Have you checked that change in your code ?

Comment: I have replaced the variable but still I am getting error in line adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, newitem); cannnot resolve the constructor.

Comment: @vimalmishra Check my updated answer. I have added Library.this in Array Adapter.

Comment: @vimalmishra Glad to help you :).Please upvote it also if it is helpful to you thanks.

Comment: @vimalmishra anything wrong with answer ? it's simply working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I kinda get what behavior you are aiming for, so I went ahead and modified your code. Here's what I've got after:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] mobileArray = {"Android", "IPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X"};
    List<String> mobileArray2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectedText;

    Button btn1, btn2;
    ArrayAdapter adapter1, adapter2;
    String[] data;
    ListView listView1, listView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_layout);

        // Initialize stuff..
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item1);
        listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item3);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mobileArray);
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mobileArray2);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        // Set set item click listener for first listview..
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
                selectedText = (String) (listView1.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
                Log.v("Print Here", selectedText);
            }
        });

        // set click listener for button 1..
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendToOtherListView(selectedText, listView2);
            }
        });
    }

    // function that accepts the string to transfer and the listview to where it will be transferred.
    private void sendToOtherListView(String strToTransfer, ListView lvDestination) {
        // gets the adapter of the destination listview..
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) lvDestination.getAdapter();

        // adds the string to transfer to the destination listview adapter.
        adapter.add(strToTransfer);
    }

}
```

It's just basic codes. Not fully optimized and all, just something you can use as a guide.

Two tips (*these tips are just what **I** think and what **I** saw that were missing or that can be added, may differ from best practices, you should search furthermore about them*):

1. I think it's much easier to use `List<String>` rather than the `String[]` for casting reasons (*this is the one I'm referring to where I'm not sure is a best practice, just the way I see it)*.
2. Add null checkers to avoid NPE.

Pretty much everything is okay, guess you just have to practice more on the data manipulation.. like for example, in your code for `setOnItemClickListener`, you retrieved the selected item, stored it in a `String[]` and set it to `adapter2` as its value, but only set the adapter for the 2nd `ListView` when button is clicked. Simpler way is like in the sample code I provided, just store the selected item text to a String variable, then only once the button is clicked, do the transfer (setting the adapter/adding the value to the adapter), that way, less unnecessary action is done.

For more info on `ListView`s, check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).

Hope this helps you somehow. Good luck and happy coding. :)

Comment: Thanks!!! .It worked and really very nice explanation. I will keep working on my coding to improve.

Comment: @vimalmishra You can only select one correct answer. Just select the one you think is the most helpful. It is confusing if our reputation keeps changing (going up and then down). Check the [How accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more details.